# How do I reach the running instance of my Thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, class, object

Basically, I have a class called Playback which extends a thread. I want to be able to run functions i have defined from this class from my thread object, but when i do they have no affect on the current thread of said object. I can only get my functions to work when called if i was .run() instead of .start() but that causes my GUI to freeze up. Here is my code

```
Playback function = new Playback(list, progBar, settings);
function.start();
function.terminate();
```

The above code does not work but the below does

```
Playback function = new Playback(list, progBar, settings);
function.run()
function.terminate();
```

When i use run though it causes my GUI to freeze. How do i call my methods on a already running thread?

Comment: Don't confuse a `Thread` object with a running thread. Also, objects don't belong to threads.

Comment: What's the code of Playback?

Comment: The second example runs on the same thread, you are only running method, in the first you are starting a thread. What does  "I can only get my functions work when called .run()" mean?

Comment: So if i start the thread how do i interact with it?

Comment: If i use .run() then when i call function .terminate() it terminates the thread- by setting the value of terminate to true- if i do the same when it is using .start() then nothing happens

Comment: You *are* interacting with it. It just doesn't do what you expect it to do. To explain why, we need to know the code, the expected behavior and the actual behavior.

Comment: Have you looked at Thread.interrupt() and Thread.isInterrupted()? This is built in functionality to facilitate what you are trying to do

Comment: @Bruce What's `Playback`. Is this your own class?

Comment: Playback is a class which extends Thread here is the code I suppose

Answer (score 0):

here is my playback class:

```
package chronos.Functions;

import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.List;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import chronos.Graphics.InputValue;

public class Playback extends Thread {
    List<InputValue> list;
    ProgressBar progBar;
    Settings settings;
    boolean terminated = false;
    public Playback(List<InputValue> list, ProgressBar progBar, Settings settings) {
        this.list = list;
        this.progBar = progBar;
        this.settings = settings;
    }
    public void run() {
    try {
        Robot bot = new Robot();
        double x = settings.getCycleNumbers();
        Thread.sleep(settings.initialDelay);
        for (double c = 0; c <= x; c++) {
            if (terminated == false) {
                System.out.println(terminated);
                System.out.println(isInterrupted());
            progBar.setProgress(c/x); 
            if (list.isEmpty() != true) {
            for (InputValue i: list) {
                if (terminated == false) {
                if (i.getType() == "key") {
                long longRuntime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                if (settings.recDurations == true) {
                    if (i.getDuration() > 0) {
                        while(i.getDuration() > System.currentTimeMillis() - longRuntime ) {
                            bot.keyPress(i.getCode());
                        }
                } else { 
                    bot.keyPress(i.getCode()); 
                }
                } else {
                    if (settings.getDurationTime() > 0) {
                        while(settings.getDurationTime() > System.currentTimeMillis() - longRuntime ) {
                            bot.keyPress(i.getCode());
                        }
                } else {
                    bot.keyPress(i.getCode()); 
                }
            }
            } else {
                bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                if (settings.recDurations == true) {
                    Thread.sleep(i.getDuration());
                } else {
                    Thread.sleep(settings.getDurationTime());
                }
                bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                if (settings.recPositions == true) {
                bot.mouseMove(i.getX(), i.getY());
                } 
            }
            if (settings.trackDelay == true) {
            Thread.sleep(i.getDelay());
            } else {
                Thread.sleep(settings.getKeyDelay());
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        Thread.sleep(settings.cycleDelay);
        } 
            } else {
                progBar.setProgress(0);
            }
        } else {
            break;
        }
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
    public void terminate() {
        System.out.println("terminated");
        terminated = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Click the edit link at the bottom of the question, and add the code in your question. Not as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How do i call my methods on a already running thread?

You can't.

A thread does what its `run()` method does.  There is no way to change that.  If you want a thread to do a certain thing, then you must create it with a run() method that does that thing.

---

Bear in mind, that there is no limit to what the run() method can do.  For example, it might wait on a BlockingQueue, for "command" objects, and each time it gets a command, it might "perform" the command.  I that case the run() method could do as many "different things" as you have different command objects that you can pass to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread doesn't terminate because you don't properly synchronize access to the `terminate` variable: one thread modifies it, and the other one reads it.

If it's not at least volatile, the Java memory model doesn't guarantee that the modification made by one thread is visible from the other one.

So, either declare your variable `volatile`, or use an AtomicBoolean, or use the native mechanism allowing to interrupt threads: call [thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29) to ask it to stop, and check for [Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) in the loop to check if the thread must stop.

The advantage of using interrupt is that the thread won't wait for `sleep()` to return before being able to stop. Instead, `sleep()` (and other blocking methods) will immediately throw an InterruptedException, signalling you that the thread has been asked to stop.